# Refresh div after form submitting with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I do have a simple form and I submit the data to my database with ajax. Everything is working fine. Right now after the form was submitted, I get an alert message with the text "Done".

My only problem is, that my div should now be automatically reloaded, so the user can see the posted result right after he clicks on the "OK" button from the alert message. Can someone tell how I can achieve that? Here is my code.

```
$(function() {
    $('#form2').on(\"submit\", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#loading').show();
            },
            complete: function(){
                $('#loading').hide();
            },
            success: function() {
                alert('Done');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<div id='refreshtodo'>
    <form name='form2' id='form2' action='./index.php' method='post'>
        <input type='text' class='big' name='duedate' size='10' maxlength='10' value='".date("d.m.Y")."'>
        <input type='submit' class='btn btn-info btn-sm' role='button' value='add'>
        <div id='loading' style='display:none;'>
            <img src=\"./bootstrap/assets/images/spinner-loading-small.gif\" alt=\"Loading - Please wait...\" />
    </form>
</div>
```

The DIV `#refreshtodo` should be reloaded, once clicked on OK in alert message!

Comment: What do you mean by 'reloaded'? To update the content of that div you would need to manually amend the DOM

Comment: I think you can send the Post data in your response from the php side. And then you can use JQuery `.html` function to change the HTML for specific html element.

Comment: Just like @hmd say... check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should `echo` the result you want to show in the div in your `index.php`, example :

```
//your index code
...

echo "this is the result".
```

Then in your js you should just print the `result` returned from your php page in the div `#refreshtodo` :

```
....
success: function(result) {
     alert('Done');
     $("#refreshtodo").html(result);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert your response data to the HTML (DOM).

Try this JS instead

```
$(function() {
    $('#form2').on(\"submit\", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(response) {
                $('#refreshtodo').html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This will remove your form from the HTML however. I would recommend creating a second div with a different ID (e.g. "#todo-response") and displaying the response there instead.

You will also need to make sure that your PHP script returns the HTML content you wish to display.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Does your `ajax` return anything that you want input into the form? Does it return HTML or json/xml?

If it's HTML

```
success: function(data) {
    alert('Done');
    $('#refreshtodo').html(data);
}
```

JSON would require you to manually map data from the object to the values within your form elements.

Currently all you have in your `#refresthtodo` is a form. So if you're just wanting to reset the form:

```
var form = document.getElementById("form2");
form.reset();
```

Comment: Thanks for your code! Inside my form there is a table within a for-loop! So every time some adds something there will be a new entry inside the table. Problem with your code is, that my complete website gets loaded inside the div once I click on OK in the alert window

Comment: @ChristophC The idea is still the same. I have no idea what is being returned from you endpoint after your ajax call. And in the code you posted, you don't document anything about a table with results/entries. I'd be happy to provide a more complete answer with a more complete question. :)